# Show a div only on small screens with jquery or css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show this html code, only on small screens.

```
<div id="NightDiv" class="w3-center" style="padding-top:20px"><i id="nightMode2" class="fa fa-moon-o fa-lightbulb-o w3-cursor-pointer w3-amazon"  aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

This is what I am trying with no success:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if ((screen.width>=1024) ) {
 $("#NightDiv").hide();
}
else {
 $("#NightDiv").show();

}
});
```

Comment: Try using `window.innerWidth`.

Comment: you could use css media queries

Comment: yep that worked @DoMiNeLa10

Answer (score 5):

You don't need JavaScript for this. Use CSS Media Query to do this,

```
/*Hide for larger screens*/
#NightDiv {
   display: none;
}

/*show for small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) { /* I've given 1023px but you can change to proper width */
    #NightDiv {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: `// comment` comments aren't valid CSS comments.

Comment: I find this method way more convenient but if he needs more control over it jQuery is the way

Answer (score 1):

This is better handled by CSS media queries. See sample below: (expand the snippet to hide the div)

```js
//no javascript!
```

```css
.w3-center {
  display: none; /* hide by default */
}

@media(max-width:1024px){
  .w3-center {
    display: block; /* or inline, or whichever style you prefer*/
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="NightDiv" class="w3-center" style="padding-top:20px"><i id="nightMode2" class="fa fa-moon-o fa-lightbulb-o w3-cursor-pointer w3-amazon"  aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="NightDiv" class="w3-center" style="padding-top:20px">
    <i id="nightMode2" class="fa fa-moon-o fa-lightbulb-o w3-cursor-pointer w3-amazon"  aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>

<style>
    #NightDiv{
        display: none;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width:768px{
        #NightDiv{
            display: block;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: You should explain what you wrote and not just blurt out markup.

Answer (score 0):

```js
ShowDiv();
$(window).resize(function() {
  ShowDiv();
});

function ShowDiv(){
      if (window.innerWidth>=1024 )
         $("#NightDiv").hide();
      else 
        $("#NightDiv").show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  id="NightDiv" class="w3-center" style="padding-top:20px;width:200px;height:100px;background-color:pink;"><i id="nightMode2" class="fa fa-moon-o fa-lightbulb-o w3-cursor-pointer w3-amazon"  aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#NightDiv').hide();
        // Display the div on mobile resoultions
        if (jQuery(window).width() < 700) {
            jQuery('#NightDiv').show();
        }
    });
```